# ffmpeg reverts to default subtitle font

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) to burn an SRT into a video file.
My code looks something like this:

```
caption_file = "captions.srt"
style = "FontName=Roboto-Regular,FontSize=8"
fonts_dir = "fonts-main/apache"

(
    ffmpeg  
    .concat(video.filter("subtitles", caption_file, fontsdir=fonts_dir, force_style=style), audio, v=1, a=1)
    .output("my_video_w_subs.mp4")
    .run()
)
```

When I run the code, the SRT indeed gets burned, but not in the specified font (Roboto-Regular).

Here are the output logs:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55adfd490e80] Loading font file 'fonts-main/apache/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55adfd490e80] Using font provider fontconfig
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55adfd490e80] fontselect: (Roboto-Regular, 400, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf, 0, DejaVuSans
```

It seems the desired font was found and loaded so I'm not sure why wasn't it used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fonts_dir` should include the font file name.

Instead of `fonts_dir = "fonts-main/apache"`, try:

```
fonts_dir = "fonts-main/apache/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
```

---

Note: `fonts-main/apache/Roboto-Regular.ttf` uses relative path.
You may try using full path like: `/fonts-main/apache/Roboto-Regular.ttf`.

---

For debugging add the argument `.global_args('-report')`, and check the log file.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
import ffmpeg

caption_file = "captions.srt"
style = "FontName=Roboto-Regular,FontSize=8"
fonts_dir = "/fonts-main/apache/Roboto-Regular.ttf"

input = ffmpeg.input('1.avi')

video = input.video
audio = input.audio

(
    ffmpeg  
    .concat(video.filter("subtitles", filename=caption_file, fontsdir=fonts_dir, force_style=style), audio, v=1, a=1)
    .output("my_video_w_subs.mp4")
    .global_args('-report')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
```

---

When using `fonts_dir = "/fonts-main/apache"`, I am getting an error `ass_read_file(/fonts-main/apache/����): fopen failed`

Note:

- I am using Windows, and I am not sure that the `fonts_dir` value is the true problem (I am not getting the `Loading font file` message).